# Parse and format Header to variable from curl response?

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl

I am trying to parse access_token string from the "Set-Cookie" header in the curl POST request executed every 10 seconds and store it in a variable.

This variable will need to be used to execute the GET request, which is every 5 minutes. The variable will be part of the request. The variable is is a access token cookie string that changes everytime the POST request is executed. This access token string will be used in the second curl request for it to run properly.

My question is, how to get only the text after "access_token=" and before the ";" ?

### Code

```
echo $(curl -D text.txt -ivk -H "Content-type: application/json"  --data '{"username":"username", "password":"password", "grant_type":"password" }' https://192.168.0.20/api/v1/auth/login | grep -Fi Set-Cookie)
echo $result
```

### Terminal response

```
$ /c/Users/mark.fomin/Desktop/test1.sh
> POST /api/v1/auth/login HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.0.20
> User-Agent: curl/7.70.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 73
>
} [73 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 73 out of 73 bytes
{ [5 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Type: application/json
< X-Powered-By: Plural
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJXQS0yMjAwIiwibmJmIjoxNjA3NDUzNDY5LCJleHAiOjE2MDc0NTM3Njl9.KG4GXVLaTQ1TCe2nxOIVjLAHZyGNizbgM0Wb94-dkZI ;refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoicmVmcmVzaF90b2tlbiIsImlzcyI6IldBLTIyMDAiLCJuYmYiOjE2MDc0NTM0NjksImV4cCI6MTYwNzQ1Mzc2OX0.hjJ6Ik5k6mVd19Yb9XVVlojq0_EIL-AGkZnSXmtdGe0; Path=/api; Secure
< Content-Length: 462
< Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2020 18:51:08 GMT
< Server: lighttpd/1.4.45
<
{ [5 bytes data]
100   535  100   462  100    73   1113    175 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1286
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.0.20 left intact
Set-Cookie: access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJXQS0yMjAwIiwibmJmIjoxNjA3NDUzNDY5LCJleHAiOjE2MDc0NTM3Njl9.KG4GXVLaTQ1TCe2nxOIVjLAHZyGNizbgM0Wb94-dkZI ;refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyb2xlIjoicmVmcmVzaF90b2tlbiIsImlzcyI6IldBLTIyMDAiLCJuYmYiOjE2MDc0NTM0NjksImV4cCI6MTYwNzQ1Mzc2OX0.hjJ6Ik5k6mVd19Yb9XVVlojq0_EIL-AGkZnSXmtdGe0; Path=/api; Secure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `awk` idea that replaces the `grep` and returns just the desired token:

```
curl ... | awk -F'[=;]' '/Set-Cookie/{gsub(" ","",$2);print $2;exit}'
```

Where:

- `-F'[=;]'` - use `=` and `;` as input field delimiters
- `/Set-Cookie/` - match any line with the string `Set-Cookie` (I'm assuming there will only be 1 such line generated by the `curl` call)
- `dsub(" ","")` - remove spaces from field #2
- `print $2` - print field #2 (the desired token)
- `exit` - we found what we want so exit

Applying this `awk` code to the text block (above, under **Terminal response**) generates:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJXQS0yMjAwIiwibmJmIjoxNjA3NDUzNDY5LCJleHAiOjE2MDc0NTM3Njl9.KG4GXVLaTQ1TCe2nxOIVjLAHZyGNizbgM0Wb94-dkZI
```

---

To store in a variable:

```
$ result=$(curl ... | awk -F'[=;]' '/Set-Cookie/{gsub(" ","",$2);print $2;exit}')
$ echo "${result}"
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJXQS0yMjAwIiwibmJmIjoxNjA3NDUzNDY5LCJleHAiOjE2MDc0NTM3Njl9.KG4GXVLaTQ1TCe2nxOIVjLAHZyGNizbgM0Wb94-dkZI
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed alternative:

```
curl ... | sed -rn '/Set-Cookie/s/(^.*Set-Cookie: access_token=)(.*$)/\2/p'
```

Look for line in the curl output with "Set Cookie" using sed and then split the line into two sections based on regular expressions. Substitute the line for the second section and print.